# How to crop multiple text from String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I want to crop a portion of String:

```java
" this is Test [ABC:123456] Sting with multiple properties [ABC:98765] ..."
```

So in result i want to crop String between "[ ]". {Here ABC:12345 and ABC:98765}
Note There can be n number of property.
what is the Best way to get result.

Comment: What do yuo mean by crop? Extract it or remove it?

Comment: Regex and group capture would be my guess.

Comment: Yes i want to extract string between []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "test bla [ABC56465:asd] asdasdqwd [DEF:345]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
        while(match.find()){
            System.out.println(match.group());
        }
    }
```

Follow the Tutorials from Niels. This could be solution.
To get the output without the "[ ]" just replace:

```
System.out.println(match.group());
```

With:

```
System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Call `match.group(1)` instead of `match.group()` if you want to capture the group without the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define you pattern and do a regex matching, extrating the group you need.

See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

for a tutorial on regex. (Especially the find() start() and end() section)

In your case the pattern should be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can do this:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\[[^\\]]*\\]", "");
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` matches the opening bracket
- The negated character class `[^\]]*` matches any character that is not a closing bracket
- `\]` matches the closing bracket
- We replace with the empty string